# Creating table using OData object model like relational database?

Tags: sql, odata, database-schema, hana

I would like to create table using OData service in SAP cloud .

As we know in  Relation database we can create table using following syntax

```
CREATE TABLE Persons(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Is there any way to achieve this for OData service ?

I couldn't find any resource regarding table creation in OData.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a table using `*.hdbdd` or `*.hdbtable` and expose it with xsodata.

Follow [SAP HANA Guide](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Developer_Guide_for_SAP_HANA_Studio_en.pdf).

Ex:

```
service namespace "HANA.Tables" {
  "Schema_Name"."PAKAGE::TABLENAME" as "NAMESPACE";
}
```